# Mongoose key/val set on instance not show in JSON or Console.. why?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have some information on my mongoose models which is transient. For performance reasons I dont wish to store it against the model.. But I do want to be able to provide this information to clients that connect to my server and ask for it.

Here's a simple example:

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
     db = require('./dbconn').dbconn;

 var PersonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
});

var Person = db.model('Person', PersonSchema);
var fred = new Person({ name: 'fred', age: 100 });
```

The Person schema has two attributes that I want to store (name, and age).. This works.. and we see in the console:

```
console.log(fred);
```

> { name: 'fred', age: 100, _id: 509edc9d8aafee8672000001 }

I do however have one attribute ("status") that rapidly changes and I dont want to store this in the database.. but I do want to track it dynamically and provide it to clients so I add it onto the instance as a key/val pair.

```
fred.status = "alive";
```

If we look at *fred* in the console again after adding the "alive" key/val pair we again see *fred*, but his status isnt shown:

> { name: 'fred', age: 100, _id: 509edc9d8aafee8672000001 }

Yet the key/val pair is definitely there.. we see that:

```
console.log(fred.status);
```

renders:

> alive

The same is true of the JSON representation of the object that I'm sending to clients.. the "status" isnt included..

I dont understand why.. can anyone help?

Or, alternatively, is there a better approach for adding attributes to mongoose schemas that aren't persisted to the database?

Comment: I think this is something quirky with mongoose objects. I always append user.avatar to be their gravatar url.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Adding the following to your schema should do what you want:

```
PersonSchema.virtual('status').get(function() {
  return this._status;
});

PersonSchema.virtual('status').set(function(status) {
  return this._status = status;
});

PersonSchema.set('toObject', {
  getters: true
});
```

This adds the virtual attribute `status` - it will not be persisted because it's a virtual. The last part is needed to make your console log output correctly. From the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html):

> To have all virtuals show up in your console.log output, set the
>   toObject option to { getters: true }

Also note that you need to use an internal property name other than `status` (here I used `_status`). If you use the same name, you will enter an infinite recursive loop when executing a get.

Comment: You can call `toObject` on your instance before sending the data. I prefer to override `toJSON` as seen [here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/mongoose-orm/SHe_Fsso_44/discussion).

Comment: You can also enable `getters` on `toJSON` as described [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toJSON) so that you don't have to override the method.

Answer (score 2):

Simply call `.toObject()` on the data object.

For you code will be like:

`fred.toObject()`

Answer (score 0):

This has been very helpful. I had to struggle with this myself.
In my case, I was getting a document from mongoose. When I added a new key, the key was not visible to the object if I console.log it. When I searched for the key (console.log(data.status), I could see it in the log but not visible if I logged the entire object.

After reading this response thread, it worked.

For example, I got an object like this one from my MongoDB call:

```
`Model.find({}).then(result=> {
    //console.log(result);// [{ name:'John Doe', email:'john@john.com'}];

    //To add another key to the result, I had to change that result like this:
    var d = result[0];
    var newData = d.toJSON();
    newData["status"] = "alive";
    console.log(newData);// { name:'John Doe', email:'john@john.com', status:'alive'};
}).catch(err=>console.log(err))`
```

Hope this helps someone else.
HappyCoding