# Is data returned from Mongoose immutable?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I want to add to the return data from a mongoose query:

```
User.findById(userId, function(err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    data.newvar = 'Hello, world';
  }
});
```

However, when I console log the output, the newvar does not exist. I've also tried this using Underscore's extend:

```
_.extend(data, {'newvar': 'Hello, world'});
```

With no luck either. Since I have nested documents, using a shallow copy won't work. Is there any way to append data here?

Answer (score 23):

One way to handle this is to convert your mongoose model instance into a plain object that you have full control over by calling [`toObject()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject) on it:

```js
User.findById(userId, function(err, data) {
  if (!err) {
    data = data.toObject();
    data.newvar = 'Hello, world';
  }
});
```

If you want a more structured solution, you can add virtual attributes to your schema as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13328312/1259510).

Comment: Thanks for this. I was passing user records from mongoose straight into JWT and the 'expiration' field wasn't getting applied for this reason. No warning or anything.

Answer (score 6):

As it turns out, Mongoose documents are their own special class and not standard Javascript objects. In order to get a javascript option that can be extended,  you must use the toObject() method.

Comment: Am I the only one thinking there should be a warning issued when you try and set values?

Comment: The .toObject() method was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use lean() method to return a plain js object:

```
User.findById(userId)
  .lean()
  .exec( function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
      data.newvar = 'Hello, world';
    }
  });
```

[Why can't you modify the data returned by a Mongoose Query (ex: findById)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504385/why-cant-you-modify-the-data-returned-by-a-mongoose-query-ex-findbyid)