# How to remove mongo specific fields from result (NodeJS, Mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to remove all Mongo specific fields (like '_id') from query result. Is there a simple method to do this or should I remove fields manually? If yes, then which are that fields and how to do that?

I'm using NodeJS and Mongoose

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a single field in MongoDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25589113/how-to-select-a-single-field-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use select() method for remove the field from your query:

```
Model.find({}).select("-removed_field").then (resp => {
// your code        
});
```

You should specified the "-" before field name, to be remove this field.
If you want remove several fields - you can specified their as array:

```
Model.find({}).select(["-removed_field1", "-removed_field2" ... ]).then (resp => {
// your code        
});
```

Also you can to select only specified fields, using this method without "-"

```
Model.find({}).select(["field1", "field2" ... ]).then (resp => {
// your code        
});
```

Comment: I must add that you can separate the fields using a simple space instead of using an array. e.g., 
Model.find({}).select('-removed_field1 -removed_field2').then....

Answer (score 5):

If you want hide `_id` property you can use text argument with prefix - which will exclude this or that field from the result, for get sepecifict fields you should pass like this:

```
Entity.find({ ... }, 'field1 field2', function(err, entity) {
    console.log(entity);  // { field1: '...', field2: '...' }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can specify a field to be excluded from results by using the optional 2nd parameter `projection` string of the `find` method:

```
Model.find({}, "-a -b").then (res => {
    // objects in the res array will all have the 
    // 'a' and 'b' fields excluded. 
});
```

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find (see `projection`)

Answer (score 1):

you can use mongoose instance method two show specific fields from all documents

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
email: {
type: String,
},

name: {
type: String,
maxlength: 128,
index: true,
trim: true,
},
});
userSchema.method({
   transform() {
   const transformed = {};
   const fields = ['name', 'email'];

      fields.forEach((field) => {
      transformed[field] = this[field];
      });
   return transformed;
   },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

OP mentioned "from result", as far as I understood, it means, removing from the query result i.e. query result will contain the field, but will be removed from the query result.

[A SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13350500/8385291) mentions, that to modify a query result (which are immutable), we've to convert the result to Object using `toObject()` method (making it mutable).

To remove a field from a query result,

```
let immutableQueryResult = await Col.findById(idToBeSearched)
let mutableQueryResult = immutableQueryResult.toObject()
delete mutableQueryResult.fieldToBeRemoved
console.log(mutableQueryResult)
```

Another way of getting the mutable result is using the `_doc` property of the result:

```
let immutableQueryResult = await Col.findById(idToBeSearched)
let mutableQueryResult = immutableQueryResult._doc    // _doc property holds the mutable object
delete mutableQueryResult.fieldToBeRemoved
console.log(mutableQueryResult)
```

Answer (score 1):

if You want to remove any specific fields like _id, You can try in two ways:
Suppose Here you try to find a user using `User` Model

```
User.find({ email: email }, { _id: 0 });
```

OR

```
const user = User.find({ email: email });
delete user._doc._id;
```